# Responsive Flexslider in Lightbox

Tags: jquery, lightbox, flexslider

I had difficulty building a responsive flexslider but managed to find a solution and thought I would share it here.

I wanted to have a flexslider carousel that fitted into the available screen size, as it was appearing inside a light box, and where the carousel images could be of different sizes and ratios and yet still fit into the slider and the screen.

There were some alternative solutions that I looked at initially which included:

1. Making all the images the same size and ratio
2. Providing the image as a background image instead of using actual
   image elements

but I wanted a solution which used the actual images.

The difficulty with Flex slider is that when you are using different sized images the key container which is the flex-viewport has its height set by the tallest image. So even if you set the width of flex-viewport the height will be determined by the tallest image. Trying to set the flex-viewport to a relative height using percentages, does not work as it is still overridden by the height of the tallest images.

It is possible to set a fixed height in pixels, but then this is obviously not going to change depending on the size of the display being used.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is really not that difficult, you just need to get the height of the display using jQuery and then set the flex-viewport height as well as the height of the images to a set pixel height based on the display height, for example:

```
 h = ($(window).height()*0.8);    
 $('.flex-viewport').height(h);
 $('.slides img').height(h);
```

to centre the images and have them fit I use the CSS:

```
img {width: auto; margin: auto;}
```

and for the main Flexslider container:

```
.flexslider {margin: auto; max-width: 90%;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't really work with displays using portrait mode or with landscape pictures with a ratio of width to height that is greater than the width to height ratio of the display. It seems the best solution would be to set the size for each image individually based on the display size and ratio. Does anyone have an answer for looping through each flexsider image and sizing each one? However, even this answer has a drawback if the display is switched between portrait and landscape mode as then everything will need resizing...